# Issues with authentication and Redux/Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, redux, react-router

**1.** How to access to Redux `dispatch` function and router `history` object in a a function like bellow

```
export const loginHelper = ({ userInfo }) => {
    dispatch(loginUser(userInfo)); // from where can i get dispatch ??
    localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(userInfo));
    history.push('/foo/search'); // from where can i get history ??
}
```

**2.** Instead of `localStorage` Where can I store my user info data so when i close the browser it gets cleared too

Answer (score 1):

Stop using localStorage
Here's the deal: most of the bad things about local storage aren't all that important. You can still get away with using it but you'll just have a slightly slower app and minor developer annoyance. 
Local storage wasn't designed to be used as a secure storage mechanism in a browser. It was designed to be a simple string only key/value store that developers could use to build slightly more complex single page apps. That's it.

What the problem really boils down to is cross-site scripting attacks (XSS).

If an attacker can run JavaScript on your website, they can retrieve all the data you've stored in local storage and send it off to their own domain. This means anything sensitive you've got in local storage (like a user's session data) can be compromised.

To answer your question, try dispatching the `userInfo` and save it in your store through reducers. then use that to query the userInfo data.